# On JetBrains GoLand why Open on GitHub action is disabled and how to enable it?

Tags: github, jetbrains-ide, goland

I installed GoLand (2019.3) via JetBrains Toolbox and I have an Ultimate account and I activated it.

I found that right click on a source code line didn't give me "Open on GitHub" button. I tried to search "Open on GitHub" action I found it is disabled (please see the two screenshots for demo). I don't know why? And I don't know how to enable it.

Can someone help? Also I am using GitHub Enterprise.

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]

Comment: By default, it works for projects hosted on github.com. If you use a custom domain name, you need to register your account under _Preferences | Version Control | GitHub_. Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the action to work you need two conditions:

- configure the custom GitHub Enterprise account in the IDE via `Settings/Preferences | Version Control | GitHub`
- have a file opened in the IDE for the action to show up

Then, this should work as expected.

Comment: if the company is using Okta for SSO of the GitHub, then probably can generate a token on the github via  settings->developer settings and use the token on Jetbrains GitHub settings.